# Notepad++ dropping tabs when files are moved between directories

Tags: backup, notepad++

I have my Notepad++ preferences set for backup, checking the options to remember current session for next launch, enable session snapshot and periodic backup, and simple backup. My default directory is set to follow current document.

Recently I moved several files to different locations in my Windows 10 directory tree. When I launched Notepad++, the tabs to those documents were lost.

Am I misunderstanding how these settings options are intended to function?

Comment: I know for sure that if a file is open in Notepad++ and you file is moved, you are asked if you want to retain the file (which is then another copy if you save it). And sounds very probable that it will just remove it if you Notepad++ was closed when you move a file. The recent list (as the last session list) has FULL path filenames. So I would say, yes, you misunderstood a bit. You should have used "save as.." from Notepad++ then it would retain the file and you can delete it on the old path.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reopening, Notepad++ loses (throws away) all tabs related to missing files, even if it has their backup in directory of saved files. So you encountered the expected behavior.

If you really want to move these files and keep them open, be sure to update their path in `session.xml` file yet before opening the Notepad++. (Use another text editor to do it.) Then you find them still present after reopening the Notepad++.